# C# WCF: Get Requesters URL

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, get, request

I have a `C# WebService` called via ajax (`javascript`).
Is it possible to retrieve the requesting URL?

Example:

`test/index.htm`l calls the WebService via "GET".
Can I retrieve this calling URL (`test/index.html`) on the server-side?

Sorry I am new to this...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done. First you need to add the following to your Web.config file

```
<configuration>   
   <system.servicemodel> 
      <servicehostingenvironment aspnetcompatibilityenabled="true">     
      </servicehostingenvironment> 
   </system.servicemodel> 
</configuration>
```

The URL that is requesting a Web Service method is known as a Referrer. The URL of a referrer is stored in the `Current` property of the `HttpContext` object of the current Http request under process. You can get this value by the following code:

```
string referrer = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

You can also use the following:

```
string referrer = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Referer];
```

The second approach basically reads the `Headers` of the Http request and fetches the value for you.

Comment: Thank you. Here I have the problem, that UrlReferrer is null. Do you know this issue?

Comment: ok, got it. It was null because of calling the service directly via the browser, not from an application. This makes sense. Thank you